# How to use setSupportActionBar in Fragment without affecting Acitivity Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-toolbar

while having two Toolbars one for activity and another for Fragment
if I set `setSupportActionBar` for the Fragment toolbar it means I am loosing `SupportActionBar` for Activity toolbar [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)). But is it possible to `setSupportActionBar` for fragment and Activity both toolbars parallel without affecting each other operating in their own scope . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do that, only a Activity has access to `setSupportActionBar`.
If you want to set it from your fragment use `((Activity)context).setSupportActionBar();`

Is your goal just changing the Title and onClick on the menu items for a Toolbar?

Edit:

Try making a toolbar object and calling
toolbar.setMenu();
and then to listen to button clicks use
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener();

Comment: actually i am having a broadcast Reciever in Activity which updates the toolbar MenuItem. but as i move to fragment SupportActionBar shifts with context to Activity as I am making my toolbar inside fragment functional. so broadcast Reciever is not relecting on the Activity toolbar

Comment: the problem is with the context. the context belongs to the Activity so `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` shifts the support for action bar from Activity to fragment. I hope you get it

Comment: So you have two Toolbars, and the broadcast is only interacting with the activity toolbar?

Comment: yup actually thats the problem I am concerned right now.

Comment: You don't have to use setSupportActionBar to change the title and menu items of a toolbar. So i would suggest not calling it in your fragment

Comment: If i dont do so an remove I am unable to access onCreateOptionsMenu() inside my fragment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151736/discussion-between-bake-and-faisal-naseer).